# Is there a way to both read and write on the rising edge of the SPI Clock?

Tags: spi, esp32

Im trying to use sipo and piso shift registers simultaneously with ESP32 using SPI. However the sipo(SN74AHC) reads data on the rising edge of clock and the piso(SN74HC165) outputs data on the rising edge of the clock. Using the arduino SPI library, there is not a spi mode that can accomidate this. As a result, I am losing a bit from either device no matter what I do.

Is there something I can do to get both read and write at the rising edge or will I be forced to read and then write, changing the spi mode in between?

Comment: Have you experimented with this?  You should still be ok with Mode 1 or 2.  You output on the rising edge and sample on the falling edge.  The PISO won't change the data bit until the next rising edge, so it will still be good to read when the clock falls.